# how does hotplug get called

Tags: usb

tweaking usb plug behavior on linux embedded platform and was just curious to know how the hotplug functionality is "exported" out of kernel.
I did see a kernel CONFIG feature for hotplug and just wondering where all are the hooks for hotplug from the core usb driver.